# Spring boot kafka consumer issue deserializing AVRO GENERIC_RECORD using Glue schema registry

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, aws-glue, avro

I have topics written by kafka connect that are in AVRO GENERIC_RECORD format using Glue Schema Registry. I am able to consume those using the documentation using a plain java program.
However I am having difficulty reading consuming them using spring boot application.

My simple config class

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration

public class KafkaAvroConsumerConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String brokers;
    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    private String groupId;

    // Creating a Listener
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        // Creating a Map of string-object pairs
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

        // Adding the Configuration
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaDeserializer.class.getName());
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaDeserializer.class.getName());

        config.put(AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.AWS_REGION, region);
        config.put(AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.REGISTRY_NAME, registryName);

        config.put(AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.AVRO_RECORD_TYPE, AvroRecordType.GENERIC_RECORD.getName());
        config.put(AWSSchemaRegistryConstants.SCHEMA_NAMING_GENERATION_CLASS,
                MySchemaNamingStrategy.class.getName());

        return config;
    }
}
```

And listener class

```
@Component

public class KafkaAvroConsumer {

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> kafkaTemplate;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "gsr1.HR.DEPARTMENTS")
    public void listenDepartment(ConsumerRecord<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> record) {

        //System.out.println("DEPARTMENTS key   schema = " + record.key().getSchema().toString());
        GenericRecord key = record.key();
        GenericRecord value = record.value();
        System.out.println("            record.key() = " + key);
        System.out.println("          record.value() = " + value);
        System.out.println("      Key  DEPARTMENT_ID = " + key.get("DEPARTMENT_ID"));
        System.out.println("         DEPARTMENT_NAME = " + (String) value.get("DEPARTMENT_NAME"));
    }

}
```

This gives me an error at "GenericRecord key = record.key();", looks like they didn't get deserialized to GenericRecord, instead they are just raw bytes

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I was looking and in spring documentation the DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory method also takes key and value deserialization class also as parameters. So I tried to do this but that doesn't compile.. GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaDeserializer doesn't take type argument either

```
    public ConsumerFactory<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> consumerFactory() {
        Deserializer<GenericRecord> avroDeser =  new GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaDeserializer();
        avroDeser.configure(consumerConfigs(), false);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), avroDeser, avroDeser);
    }
```

Any help in how to get this to work.
I put the question out in GSR github too https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-schema-registry/issues/241

Here is the POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootKafkaAvro</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootKafkaAvro</name>
    <description>Spring boot Kafka Avro using Glue Schema registry</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.glue</groupId>
            <artifactId>schema-registry-serde</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: So the factory didn't compile, so where else is `consumerConfigs()` actually being used? In the logs, are you seeing `value.deserializer = ... StringDeserializer`, then? Why not configure deserializers [in the properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka)?

Comment: Could you please add your pom.xml (At least the dependencies concerning kafka and the schema registry). Also just as a naive question, have you generated the necessary classes from the avro schema(s)
And as mentioned by @OneCricketeer what about application.properties?

Comment: POM added @Csisanyi. Topics are written using the Kafka connect as GenericRecord., so no need for avro schema classes.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, ConsumerConfigs() are only used in the ConsumerFactory. properties are set below, key and value are avro. And using springboot they are not deserializing key or value and it gives the above error (cant cast string to genericrecord). Works fine in regular java program.

        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaDeserializer.class.getName());
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaDeserializer.class.getName());

Comment: Spring is still a "regular java program". If your method is never used, spring-kafka simply defaults to use StringDeserializer. Why not use property file?

Comment: What I meant by regular java program is not using springboot.
Both consumer properties and glue configs are set in consumerConfigs() method. consumerConfigs() are used as argument in building consumerFactory(), and consumerFactory() is used as a argument in concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory(). So everything is set properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the issue is. In the config class SpringBoot expects the factory bean name to be **kafkaListenerContainerFactory**. I named it **concurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory** which is causing the issue of not loading the consumer and glue configurations properly.

> By default, a bean with name **kafkaListenerContainerFactory** is
> expected.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#kafka-listener-annotation